# how to set the directory for user directive in CentOS

Tags: apache, web, centos

I can get access to
http://host/~user1/index.html
by following some online instructions (edit userdir.conf)

However, I cant find any information for getting access to the user directive its directory, say, if I create folderX under public_html, I would like to access the folder like this: http://host/~user1/folderX; then it will show the index of the "folderX" directory. (Now I got 403 forbidden message, You don't have permission to access /~user1/folderX/ on this server.)

As you know, if we create a folder, say, folder1, under "/var/www/html/" directory, we can get access to the folder http://host/folder1 directly and it will list the index of the directory.

So, could anyone help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you want user directories:

1) You must enable mod_userdir module in your Apache runtime

2) You can add additional UserDir stanzas in your Apache configuration file

3) Each user who wishes must create a directory ~/public_html ("public_html" is the default name) under their home directory.

4) Any subdirectories the user creates are by default accessible from a web browser.  The behavior is the same as the "main" page in /var/www/html/.

Here are two links that might help:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html
- http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/10/how-to-enable-and-configure-apache2-userdir-module-in-ubuntu-server-12-04.html

Comment: @ paulsm4, I have followed your web to setup user directive, say, `http://host/~user1` will directly go to `http://host/~user1/index.html`   rather than just the folder ~user1. I wonder if I could just create a sub-folder and get access to it by using the user directive, say, create a sub-folder called 111 under public_html and get access like: `http://host/~user1/111`,  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking ... but if you want Apache to show the *contents* of a directory ... then you need to configure [Options +Indexes](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) in your Apache configuration: http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/